# Possible to have a class dedicated to exception handling c#

Tags: c#, exception

I am developing a windows application in VS2015
My query is regarding two possible methods of handling system defined exceptions:
-   Use try blocks in where ever possible and handle it
-   Define an exception class and write down all possible exceptions (I am focusing only system defined exceptions like File Not Found, Null Reference ) and inherit that class in other classes which automatically will handle the exceptions.
Could anybody please advice me which method is better and if the second method is better, how to implement and use it .My classes already inherits from Form. So do I need an interface? If so where I can implement the methods?
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would be a really bad idea. Generally exceptions need specific handling. So if you caught a `NullReferenceException`, what would you do in the handler? You would have no idea how to recover. The only thing that might be useful is a very generic error message (i.e. "An error happened, sorry") or logging.

Comment: Use the third option: add a try-catch at the lowest level, and handle your general exceptions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 2 is possible. I would recommend it if you always expect the same kind of exceptions.

If the called methods can throw very specific exceptions, it might be better to handle them close to where they are thrown.

You can define a wrapper method to catch exceptions like this:

```
public bool TryExecuteServiceAction(Action a) {

    if (a == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("a");
    }

    try {
        a();
        return true;
    }
    catch (SecurityAccessDeniedException sade) {
        Logger.Error(sade);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Extend this pattern by returning a `ResultObject` that contains an error code, message etc. instead of returning `bool`.

Use the wrapper like this

```
DoSomethingDto serviceResult = null;
var success = TryExecuteServiceAction(() => serviceResult = _service.DoSomething(command));
if (success) {
    // we know that the service call was successful and the DTO has data
    // work with DTO ...
}
else {
    // e.g. show generic error message to user
}
```